# What is the least order type of this set?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, ordinals

Working in ZFC - Infinity, lets say that there exists two sets $A, B$ that are nonempty and mutually disjoint, and $A$ is well ordered by relation $<^A$, and $B$ is well ordered by relation $<^B$. Now an *initial segment* $A^-$ of $A$ is defined as a subset of $A$ that is closed under $<^A$, and similarly define initial segments of $B$. Of course $A,B$ are initial segments of themselves. Now let $A$ be isomorphic to some *proper* $B^-$, that is: $$\exists f (f: A \to B^- \land \\ f \text{ is bijective } \land \\\forall x,y \in A [x <^A y \leftrightarrow f(x) <^B f(y)])$$

Now I want to coin a sort of *definitional equivalence* between subsets of $A$ and subsets of $B$, so we say that a subset $S^A$ of $A$ that is definable after a formula $\phi^A$ whose variables range over $A \cup P(A)$ and that uses $=,\in, <^A$ relation symbols is *definitionally equivalent to* a subset $S^B$ that is definable after the formula $\phi^B$ which is the formula obtained from $\phi^B$ by replacing every occurrence of the $A$ symbol by the symbol $B$, and all of its variables are taken to range over $B \cup P(B)$, examples are the set which only contain the initial element of $A$ with respect to $<^A$, this is definitially equivalent to the set that only contain the initial element of $B$ with respect to $<^B$; another example is $A$ and $B$ themselves, they are definitially equivalent after formula $\forall x (x \in X \leftrightarrow x \in A)$.

Now comes the question: if we say that for any formula $\phi$ if $A^-$ is definable after $\phi$ and its definitional equivalent is isomorphic to it, then $A^- \neq A$ that is: there is an element of $A$ such that all elements of $A^-$ has the relation $<^A$ to; then:

> what's the least possible order type of set $A$?

Comment: Your requirement that $A\not\cong B$ is redundant: we can't have $A\cong B-$ and $A\cong B$ for $B^-$ a proper initial segment of $B$ since then $B$ would be a well-ordering isomorphic to a proper initial segment of itself, and this can't happen. In fact, rather than initial segment embeddings at all, just talk about longer/shorter ordinals.

Comment: Also, in your question are you asking for the smallest ordinal $A$ having this property with respect to **some**, or to **every**, larger ordinal $B$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, thanks for pointing the redundancy. I'll correct it. As regards your second comment, I mean to **some**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rephrasing to use more standard terminology, you're looking at **second-order-definable subsets of ordinals**. Specifically, say that $(\alpha,\beta)$ is a **good pair** if $\alpha<\beta$ and for every second-order formula $\varphi$ we have $$\varphi^\alpha\cong\varphi^\beta\implies \varphi^\alpha\not=\alpha.$$

(Note that replacing "$\not=$" with "$\not\cong$" in the right hand side won't lead to a different notion, since we can take collapses in a second-order-definable manner.) The following shows that good pairs have to be ridiculously large:

> Suppose there is a second-order sentence $\theta$ such that $\theta$ pins down $\alpha$ (that is, $\mathcal{A}\models\theta$ iff $\mathcal{A}\cong\alpha$). Then there is no $\beta$ such that $(\alpha,\beta)$ is a good pair.

Put another way:

> Let $\sigma$ be the least ordinal not pinned down by a second-order sentence. If $(\alpha,\beta)$ is a good pair then $\sigma<\alpha$.

*Proof*: Fix such an $\alpha,\theta$. Consider the second-order formula $\hat{\theta}(x)\equiv$ "No initial segment below $x$ satisfies $\theta$." We have $\hat{\theta}^\beta=\alpha$ for all $\beta\ge \alpha$. $\quad\Box$

And $\sigma$ is **gigantic**. Specifically, we have:

> **Proposition**. Suppose $T$ is any computable (or indeed projective) first-order theory in the language of set theory such that some level of $L$ satisfies $T$. Letting $\alpha_T=\min\{\alpha: L_\alpha\models T\}$, we then have $\sigma>\alpha_T$.

And from this we get:

> **Corollary**. Suppose $T$ is a computable (or indeed projective) first-order theory in the language of set theory such that $T$ has a transitive model. Then $\sigma$ is greater than the shortest height of a transitive model of $T$.

So, for example, $\sigma$ is greater than the minimal height of a transitive model of ZFC + "There is a proper class of supercompacts," assuming there are transitive models of the latter in the first place.

*Proof of corollary.* Apply the Proposition to $T'=$ ZFC+ "$T$ has a transitive model" and use Shoenfield absoluteness to say that $T'$ holds in some level of $L$ if $T$ has a transitive model in $V$. $\quad\Box$

*Proof of proposition.* By Condensation we know $\alpha_T<\omega_1^L$. The key fact now is that the set of $\alpha<\omega_1$ such that $L_\alpha$ is pointwise-definable is cofinal in $\omega_1^L$. If $\beta<\alpha_T$, let $\gamma$ be the smallest ordinal $>\alpha_T$ such that $L_\gamma$ is a pointwise-definable model of ZFC+V=L and let $\varphi^{L_\gamma}=\{\beta\}$. Then $\beta$ is the unique ordinal $\gamma$ such that there is a pointwise-definable model $M$ of ZFC+V=L satisfying "$\alpha_T$ exists and there is no pointwise-definable level of $L$ satisfying $ZFC$ of height $>\alpha_T$" such that $\varphi^M\cong\gamma$. Since WLOG $\beta$ is infinite, and all the structures we're considering are countable by Condensation, we can talk about existence of such structures in $\beta$ in a second-order way ("There is a family of relations on me such that ..."). $\quad\Box$

---

On the other hand, we do at least get that $\sigma<\omega_1$. This raises the natural question:

> Is there a good pair $(\alpha,\beta)$ with $\alpha$ countable?

The answer to this is **yes**: by a straightforward counting argument, there is some $\alpha<\omega_1$ such that no subset of $\omega_1$ of ordertype $\alpha$ is second-order definable in $\omega_1$. Then $(\alpha,\omega_1)$ forms a good pair.

*This*, in turn, raises one last natural question:

> Is there a good pair $(\alpha,\beta)$ with $\beta$ countable?

The pigeonhole principle trick in the previous bulletpoint doesn't work here. Moreover, note that $\omega_1$ is pinned down by a second-order sentence, so we're not going to find a "sufficiently $\omega_1$-like" ordinal to just trivially reflect the argument above.

I don't immediately have an answer to this question.

Comment: why did you put gigantic in bold?

Comment: @Zuhair For emphasis. It's really gigantic.

Comment: If its countable, then in what sense its gigantic?

Comment: @Zuhair I guess if you consider everything countable to be small, it's not gigantic. But in the context of providing **concrete definitions** of ordinals, moving up in the countable ordinals yields more and more undefinability phenomena. The example in this case is rather extreme in that sense. Since that's relevant here, that's what I'm using. It's not worth arguing about though.

Comment: @Ah! you are speaking in the sense of large countable ordinals.

Comment: For example, $\sigma$ is much larger than the smallest height of a transitive model of ZFC+"There is a proper class of supercompact cardinals" assuming there is such a model in the first place.

Comment: What? That's really gigantic!

Comment: I think such a thing needs to be explained in the answer, I mean a little bit. I know that you've alluded to it in the answer, but I think this needs some addressing.

Comment: @Zuhair Sure - later today when I have time I'll expand on the relevant line ("For example, if $\alpha$ is the least ordinal such that $L_\alpha\models\psi$ for some first-order sentence $\psi$, then $\alpha$ can be pinned down in this way since in a second-order way we can talk about the construction of $L$ along $\alpha$").

Comment: Thanks! So what's the consistency strength of "ZFC+ there exists a good pair"?

Comment: from these notes can I infer that "ZFC + there exists a good pair" cannot have any level $L$ that satisfy it?

Comment: @Zuhair No. As I showed above, ZFC proves just by a pigeonhole principle argument that there is some countable $\alpha$ such that $(\alpha,\omega_1)$ is a good pair. Indeed much less than ZFC is needed to prove this. The interesting question is whether "There is a good pair with both entries countable" is even consistent over ZFC ...