# What's the limit to formation of ordinals using size-bounded good pairs?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, ordinals, large-cardinals

for the same question in a prior [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3631864/what-is-the-least-order-type-of-this-set/3631913?noredirect=1#comment7468160_3631913), add the following size-bounding condition, that is: any subset of $A$ that is equal in size to a proper initial segment of $A$, is bounded in $A$ (with respect to $<^A$). The same property is to be applied to $B$.

The same question is to be placed but with the above condition holding, that is:

> What's the least order type of $A$?

I'm under the impression that this must be a large cardinal, but I'm not sure of that.

Comment: Isn't this condition just equivalent to being regular? If A is regular, then any initial segment must be less than |A|, so if C satisfy those terms we have, |C|<|A|, then C is bounded in A.
$$$$(For continent sake, assume A is ordinal) If (A,∈) satisfy those conditions, and C is subset of A such that |C|<|A|, then there |C| is of equal size as C, and |C| is bounded in |A|, so C is also bounded in A. That means that |C|=|A|, but if so we can just take C=A.

Comment: @ℋolo, Yes $A$ is regular, but which one? For example $\omega$ is regular, but it's not the order type of $A$, it cannot be a successor cardinal, because we can define successor cardinals by being the set of all ordinals equinumerous to the predecessor cardinal, and this would lead to isomorphism with its $B$ equivalent of, so it cannot be it, now if we take it an inaccessible ordinal, then this also can be defined in a manner leading to isomorphic $B$ equivalent. So where that stops? Is it at the first Mahlo? or even beyond it? where?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't follow your previous post, I just wanted to point out that "size-bounding condition" is just being regular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same counting argument as in your other question gives a not-too-big upper bound - namely, $\aleph_{\omega_1+1}$ *(remember that $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ isn't regular)*. Specifically, there are only countably many definable (in the sense of second-order logic, or indeed with respect to any fixed countable logic) subsets of $\aleph_{\omega_1+1}$ but uncountably many regular cardinals $<\aleph_{\omega_1+1}$, so there must be some regular cardinal $\kappa<\aleph_{\omega_1+1}$ such that $(\kappa,\aleph_{\omega_1+1})$ is a good pair.

Of course, in the context of cardinals $<\aleph_{\omega_1}$ this $\kappa$ must be extremely large, just as the smallest element of a good pair in general must be extremely large in the context of countable ordinals. (The "$<\aleph_{\omega_1}$" isn't a typo: since $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal, $\kappa<\aleph_{\omega_1+1}$ implies $\kappa<\aleph_{\omega_1}$.)

Comment: But $\aleph_{\omega_1 +1}$ is definable! its the class of all ordinals injective to $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ and since $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ is isomorphic to its equivalent, then so its successor?

Comment: @Zuhair I don't understand your comment. I'm saying that that the pigeonhole principle means that for some regular $\kappa<\aleph_{\omega_1}$ we have that $(\kappa,\aleph_{\omega_1+1})$ is a good pair. I'm not saying that $\aleph_{\omega_1+1}$ is the $A$-part of a good pair, but the $B$-part.

Comment: @Oh I see, my bad, sorry, I need to think of this.

Comment: can this occur in a true well founded model of ZF ( I mean externally)? the idea is that if $A$ is regular then its the first of all initial segments of $A$ that are not the first projection of a good pair, but since $A$ is of successor cardinality [working in ZF] then clearly it would be pinned also,  so it cannot be the first projection of a good pair. So $A$ must be a limit cardinal! And so inaccessible.

Comment: @Zuhair I don't really understand your comment - what is $A$ here, the least first projection of a good pair? If so, $A<\aleph_{\omega_1}$ as per my answer and hence (being regular) $A$ is indeed a successor cardinal. But there's no contradiction here. While $A$ is second-order definable over its cardinal predecessor, that cardinal predecessor itself need not (indeed will not) be pinned down by a second-order sentence.

Comment: Well possibly I'm confused, I was thinking that this woult lead to an infinitely decreasing chain of non pinned cardinals, thus violating the external well ordering.

Comment: @Zuhair Why would it do that? The first unpinned cardinal is a limit cardinal $<\aleph_{\omega_1}$, by a direct counting argument (+ the fact that any successor cardinal is "pinned relative to its predecessor"), but that's not a problem. (Note that pinned-ness has nothing to do with regularity - *you* brought regularity into the picture in your specific modification of good pairs above, but that doesn't impact the general behavior of pinning down cardinals by second-order sentences.)

Comment: @OK! that' fine! Thanks!

Comment: that limit cardinal cannot be singular (if the model is externally well founded), because it would be the union of a pinned set of pinned sets, so of course it would be pinned also. So it must be regular, but by then it would be inaccessible.

Comment: @Zuhair "it would be the union of a pinned set of pinned sets" No - or at least, not in the sense you want. It is indeed a supremum of pinned ordinals, but those ordinals are not in any way "uniformly" pinned so we can't turn that into a contradiction (note that pinnedness itself isn't second-order definable). That is, "union of a pinned number of pinned sets" is very different from "pinned union of pinned sets" - the latter, which is what you would need to get a contradiction, requires that the ordinals be pinned in a somehow uniform way.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks a lot!