# What's the order type of the least good pair with that additional qualification?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, ordinals, large-cardinals

In this posting I'll add a further condition on ***good pairs*** which were defined in a [prior posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3631864/what-is-the-least-order-type-of-this-set/), I'll re-iterate the definition with the added condition:

A good pair $\langle A,B \rangle$ is an ordered pair fulfilling the following conditions:

- $A,B$ are disjoint nonempty well ordered sets.
- Let $\varphi^A,\varphi^B$ be the respective initial segments (i.e., subsets of $A,B$ closed under the respective well order) that are definable in the language of set theory (+ *primitive* constants $A,B$) by the formula $\varphi$ relativized to the union of the respective set with its power; then: $$\varphi^A \cong \varphi^B \iff \varphi^A \neq A$$
- $|A|,|B|$ are regular.

The idea is to blow up these pairs to the inaccessible realm.

Now adding primitive constants $A,B$ to the language of ZFC, and working in ZFC + a good pair exists:

> What would be the least possible order type of set $A$?

Comment: Since the definitions aren't that long, you should make this question more self-contained.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I'll try! Thanks!

Comment: No, I mean $\iff$ specifically, that's the addition really!

Comment: Adding constants for the whole well-order isn't necessary: $A$ is a definable element of $\mathcal{P}(A)$.

Comment: (And below my incorrect answer, you wrote: "ANY subset of $A$
 is definable in terms of $A$ itself." That's false: using $A$ as a parameter, or indeed any fixed $X\subseteq A$ as a parameter, still only allows us to define as many subsets of $A$ as there are formulas in our logic.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous answer was incorrect *(and the comments below are no longer relevant)*. In fact, it's easy to see that now you do reach all the way up to inaccessibles.

*To avoid confusion with previous questions, I'll call your modified notion "very good pairs."*

For $\alpha$ a regular cardinal, let $reg(\alpha)$ be the ordertype of the set of regular cardinals $<\alpha$. Clearly $reg$ is injective on the regular cardinals: if $\alpha<\beta$ are regular then $reg(\alpha)<reg(\beta)$. And letting $Reg(\alpha)$ be the initial segment of $\alpha$ with ordertype $reg(\alpha)$, it's not hard to show that $Reg(\alpha)$ is a second-order-definable subset of $\alpha$.

Now suppose $(\alpha,\beta)$ is a very good pair. Then since $reg$ is injective we have $Reg(\alpha)\not\cong Reg(\beta)$. Hence we must have $Reg(\alpha)=\alpha$ - which is to say, $\alpha$ must be inaccessible.

- Note that we're getting all of this strength from the new direction of the bi-implication in the definition: $(\alpha,\beta)$ is a *merely* good pair if (not iff) $\alpha$ isn't second-order definable in $\beta$, and that's a phenomenon which happens pretty low down by a simple pigeonhole argument.

In fact, though, we can go much further. Let $inac, Inac$ be the analogous "inaccessible-counting" functions. Suppose $(\alpha,\beta)$ is a very good pair. We know that $\alpha$ is inaccessible, so $inac(\alpha)<ina(\alpha)+1\le inac(\beta)$ and consequently we have $Inac(\alpha)\not\cong Inac(\beta)$. This means we must have $inac(\alpha)=\alpha$. So $\alpha$ is $2$-inaccessible. And we keep going up the inaccessibility hierarchy for as long as we can keep everything nicely second-order definable!

What about an upper bound? Well, there's a second-order sentence $\pi$ such that $\gamma\models\pi$ iff $\gamma$ is "sufficiently greater than" the least very good pair (specifically: $\gamma$ needs to be bigger than the powerset of the right coordinate of some very good pair). So we trivially get - assuming that very good pairs exist in the first place - that the following ordinal is an upper bound for the least very good pair:

> Let $\theta$ be the smallest ordinal such that for every second-order sentence $\pi$, if all sufficiently large ordinals satisfy $\pi$ then $\theta$ satisfies $\pi$.

---

Of course this leaves open the big question:

> Is the existence of very good pairs in fact consistent with ZFC at all?

I suspect the answer is yes, but at the moment I don't see it.

Comment: Yes. But we still need to know at which ordinal that would stop? I think the pigeonhole argument you used might limit that to below the next inaccessible? A kind of a gigantic (local) ordinal below it? something like that? just a guess.

Comment: @Zuhair It goes way above the next inaccessible - see my edit.

Comment: hmmm... I see, thanks. The consistency question is nice really!